# Optimizing Variable and Year Merge Code Across Many CSVs in R

Tags: r

economics research assistant here. I'm working with R to merge the College Scorecard and IPEDS datasets to output to a single CSV to run OLS in Stata. I'm pretty happy with the College Scorecard merge code, but while the IPEDS merge code works, it's pretty gross, and I'd love help optimizing it. Below is a snippet of one of the merge code for one of the years for one of the variables. If it would help to look at the structure of the dataset, let me know and I'll see how I can post the datasets.

```
# 1.2.1.1 - 2008
ipeds2008ControlTuitionSTFRAdmissions = read.csv(file = file.path(ipedsDir, "2008ControlTuitionSTFRAdmissions.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ipeds2008Gender = read.csv(file = file.path(ipedsDir, "2008Gender.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ipeds2008Grad = read.csv(file = file.path(ipedsDir, "2008Grad.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ipeds2008Race = read.csv(file = file.path(ipedsDir, "2008Race.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

.
.
.
# 1.2.2.1 - 2008
ipeds2008GenderGrad = merge(ipeds2008Gender, 
                            ipeds2008Grad)
ipeds2008GenderGradRace = merge(ipeds2008GenderGrad, 
                                ipeds2008Race)
ipeds2008 = merge(ipeds2008GenderGradRace, 
                  ipeds2008ControlTuitionSTFRAdmissions)

# Garbage management.
rm(ipeds2008Gender, 
   ipeds2008ControlTuitionSTFRAdmissions, 
   ipeds2008GenderGrad,
   ipeds2008GenderGradRace,
   ipeds2008Race,
   ipeds2008Grad)
.
.
.
# Now, let's merge all the IPEDS years.
ipedsMerged = Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(ipeds2008, 
                                                                ipeds2009, 
                                                                ipeds2010, 
                                                                ipeds2011, 
                                                                ipeds2012,
                                                                ipeds2013,
                                                                ipeds2014,
                                                                ipeds2015,
                                                                ipeds2016,
                                                                ipeds2017))
.
.
.
# Now, let's merge all the IPEDS years.
ipedsMerged = Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(ipeds2008, 
                                                                ipeds2009, 
                                                                ipeds2010, 
                                                                ipeds2011, 
                                                                ipeds2012,
                                                                ipeds2013,
                                                                ipeds2014,
                                                                ipeds2015,
                                                                ipeds2016,
                                                                ipeds2017))

# Because we currently have each variable year as a separate variable (with nulls in observation years that
# aren't in that year), we want to merge all the variable years into one variable, if that makes sense. Dplyr's
# coalesce function is very good at that. Let's start with the public vs private variable.
ipedsMerged$institutionalControl = coalesce(ipedsMerged$IC2008.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2009.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2010.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2011.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2012.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2013.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2014.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2015.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2016.Institutional.control.or.affiliation,
                                            ipedsMerged$IC2017.Institutional.control.or.affiliation)

# Dropping all the rows that we don't need now.
ipedsMerged = ipedsMerged[ , !(names(ipedsMerged) %in% c("IC2008.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2009.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2010.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2011.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2012.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2013.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2014.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2015.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2016.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IC2017.Institutional.control.or.affiliation",
                                           "IDX_EF",
                                           "IDX_GR"))]
.
.
.
ipedsTbl = as_tibble(ipedsMerged)

# Let's do some more garbage management.
rm(ipeds2008,
   ipeds2009,
   ipeds2010,
   ipeds2011,
   ipeds2012,
   ipeds2013,
   ipeds2014,
   ipeds2015,
   ipeds2016,
   ipeds2017,
   ipedsMerged)


# 1.3 - For the piece de resistance, let's merge ipeds and college scorecard.
ipedsCS = left_join(ipedsTbl, csTbl, by = c("unitid" = "unitid", "year" = "year"))

write_csv(ipedsCS, path = file.path(thisDir, "Data", "Merged", "ipedsCS.csv"))
```

Comment: Put all your files in one folder, set wd to that, use list.files. Might be quicker(easier).

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your requirements are where. What assumptions can be made about the input? What is the exact desired output? Without anyway to test the code it's hard to help.